# connecting a C# application to Xeround cloud Database

Tags: c#, database, xeround

Hello I am trying to connect my c# application I used this code I found on net but it doest seem to work here is the code

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=ayoya;" +
                                   "password=12333;" + 
                                    "server=instance28181.db.xeround.com:18422;" +
                                   "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                   "database=salam;" +
                                   "connection timeout=30;");
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();

        }
        catch (Exception a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("Failed");
        }
```

can someone please tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, after connecting to the instance creating a DB (using CREATE DATABASE), you must make sure the following parameters contain the correct arguments:

`Hostname` – See DNS Name in the Details tab; `port #`– appears by the hostname; `username` & `password` – the username and password you provided for the DB instance (also appears in Details tab); `database` – the name of the DB (NOT the instance name) to which you‘re trying to connect.

Now, more specifically, try the following code to connect your c# application to your xeround DB:

```
MySqlConnection con = new
  MySqlConnection("Server=instance28181.db.xeround.com;
  Port=18422;Database=salam;Uid=ayoya;Pwd=1233");
```

Good luck ;)